# Deploy angular 5 and rails on same ec2 server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, amazon-ec2

I have done server side coding in rails 5.2 and client in angular 5. For rails I am using puma sever. After the development, now I am looking to deploy both
(client and server code) in production server(AWS ec2). In server, I have ngnix web server and I have configured two server one for angular on port 80 and another for rails on port 81.

I have generated a production build of angular project and saved in the ngnix root path.

Initially I have used the following command
    RACK_ENV=production bundle exec
But server is getting stopped after a few hour. Then I used 'rails s &' to run the server.

Now I am able to access the project from the browser. But not able to load images uploaded to server with path (site_url/path_to_file).
Am I on the correct track? If so, how to fix the image url issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you are deploying this the wrong way. You don't serve a Rails app this way, running it with "rails s". Usually you use a webserver (nginx, apache, etc...) and an application server (like Phusion Passenger).

The application server runs the rails app (it can run several other kind of applications, like node) and the webserver receives all income request and redirects to the application server, that handles to which application the request will be passed.
[Here](https://www.hugeserver.com/kb/how-serve-ruby-rails-app-nginx-passenger-ubuntu16/) is explained how to set up this.

If you donṕ t want to use Passenger and wants to only use Puma + Ngix, take a look [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04). You have to use puma-manager.

The Angular app is a "simple" html/css/js application. Only static files. So it can be served this way.
Take a look at the official doc, there it is explained how to [build](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build) and [deploy](https://angular.io/guide/deployment).

Comment: so when we request for a url which one get invoked rials or angular?

Comment: It will depend on how you will set up the server blocks (apache name this as 'virtual hosts'). Take a look here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: You don't need one webserver running for each "site" you want to serve. You should have only one webserver running that listens to the port 80 and it will be configured (by the server blocks) to handle multiple dns.